# I have some issue about hover and transition effect

Tags: html, css

When i testing the Hover effect and also the transition effect but it doesn't working. I can not find any problem. Please Help me. What should i do now.
What is the problem??

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="test">
             <a href="#"><h1>This is header</h1></a>
             <div class="images"><img src="img/them.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Css

```
   .container{
    width:900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.test{}
.test h1{
    font-size:30px;
    position:relative;
}
.images {
    width: 258px;
    position:absolute;
    right:100px;
    transition:.5s;
}
.images img{
    width:100%;
}
 .test h1:hover .images {
    left:0px;

}
```

Comment: @zgood it's inside the `a`

Comment: @ThomasYates you are correct... must have missed it

Comment: i tried with the a tag. But it still not working

Comment: @Runa You have not accepted answers of any of your previous questions. [Info about how to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missing a sibling selector:

```
.test a:hover ~ .images {
  display: none;
}
```

**Snippets:**

```css
.container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.test {}

.test h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.images {
  width: 258px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.images img {
  width: 100%;
}

.test a:hover~.images {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">
    <a href="#">
      <h1>This is header</h1>
    </a>
    <div class="images">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to apply `transition` on `left`:

```css
.container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.test {}

.test h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.images {
  width: 258px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  left: calc(100% - 358px);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: left .5s;
}

.images img {
  width: 100%;
}

.test a:hover~.images {
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">
    <a href="#">
      <h1>This is header</h1>
    </a>
    <div class="images">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Docs:**

- [transition - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)
- [General sibling combinator | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

Comment: I believe this is the best approach, although assigning the hover pseudo-class to the `a` element could be confusing, especially if the position attributes for the header change. Perhaps moving the image to the same level as the header and using the sibling selector with the `h1`could be a better solution

Comment: can you please told me why my transition effect doesn't working?

Comment: @Runa You can achieve the similar effect using `opacity` CSS property. Check my updated answer above. Your `transition` property value was not correct.

Comment: but if i  want to move the photo in left side without hiding it. What should i do then? With the transition effect

Comment: @Runa Please check my updated answer with 2nd snippet. Read up the `transition` related document I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML doesn't match the rule you wrote:

```
 .test h1:hover .images {
    display:none;
}
```

There are a couple things you might be trying to do:

```
 .test a:hover + .images {
    display:none;
}
```

That will hide `.images` when you hover the `h1`. However, since your h1 is inside of an `<a>` you'll need to either remove that or put a class on the `<a>` and reference that instead of the h1. Or you can move the images div inside of the h1 and it will match the existing rule.

Comment: `.test h1:hover + .images` will not work. `+` is for selecting elements that are placed immediately after another element. `.images` is immediately after the `a` tag not the `h1` tag.

Comment: This wouldn't work as the `h1` is within the `a` and not a sibling before `.images`

Comment: Aw, ninja'd .. :(

Comment: That's why I added the explanation afterwards. But I've changed my answer to reflect what the CSS should be to work instead of what I thought they were trying to accomplish.